# Trying to understand obscure behavior when forming a single dictionary object from 2 distinct dictionaries with **kwargs syntax

Tags: python, string, oop, dictionary, keyword-argument

I am attempting to understand a piece of code that involves a bit of use of the **kwargs when a function gets called. After reading through the Pydocs and some other posts on Stackoverflow, I attempted to experiment with this syntax interactively and encountered some cases where I could not understand the behavior:

```
In [180]: d1 = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}

In [181]: d2 = {'e':'f', 'g':'h', 'i':'j'}

In [182]: dict(d1, d2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-49f16d5922b6> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(d1, d2)

TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

In [183]: dict(d1, **d2)
Out[183]: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'i': 'j'}

In [184]: dict(d1, *d2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-0d16a1c0b887> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(d1, *d2)

TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

In [185]: dict(*d1,d2)
  File "<ipython-input-185-d36e77e65d5e>", line 1
    dict(*d1,d2)
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression


In [186]: dict(**d1,d2)
  File "<ipython-input-186-fd4b93fcc3c9>", line 1
    dict(**d1,d2)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the code that I am currently studying, I see the syntax of `In [183]` being used and from what currently I understand of `**d2` when it is used as such is that it expands the dictionary object `d2` in place into a tuple of that looks like `(e=f, g=h, i=j)` so the statement for `In [183]` could look like (I'm not sure which one, but I tired all possibilities I could think of and none worked which puzzles me):

```
In [192]: dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, (e=f, g=h, i=j))
  File "<ipython-input-192-792b64fb793a>", line 1
    dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, (e=f, g=h, i=j))
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

for this above, I thought the brackets enclosing `e=f, g=h, i=j` might be the problem because this works:

```
In [191]: dict(a=5,l=6)
Out[191]: {'a': 5, 'l': 6}
```

but when I removed them, I get:

```
In [196]: dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, e=f, g=h, i=j)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-196-854a7d483a98> in <module>()
----> 1 dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, e=f, g=h, i=j)

NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

and trying just the `e=f, g=h, i=j` portion alone does not work:

```
In [197]: dict(e=f, g=h, i=j)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-b53d153dfd98> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(e=f, g=h, i=j)

NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

and then I realized that putting the `''` around f, h and i solved the problem:

```
In [199]: dict(e='f', g='h', i='j')
Out[199]: {'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'i': 'j'}
```

So I guess what I found here was that the right hand side of the key=value pair does not need to be defined as a string or perhaps any object type for that matter, but why is this so?

and when I went back to the original issue, I had

```
In [200]: dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, e='f', g='h', i='j')
Out[200]: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'i': 'j'}
```

And so it finally worked!

Sorry if I have been not clear on what my issues are here, so to just summarize, I will list out all my questions on this:

1. How is it that when I did `In [183]: dict(d1, **d2)` it worked and I did not get any errors relating to the number of arguments, whereas for `In [182]: dict(d1, d2)` and `In [184]: dict(d1, *d2)` I got errors telling me that I have put in more arguments to `dict` than what it accepts? How did `d1, **d2` turn into a single argument?
2. From the errors in doing `In [185]: dict(*d1,d2)` and `In [186]: dict(**d1,d2)`, it seems clear the having `*` or `**` to the first dictionary object does not work. Why can't this be done? For example, why doesn't `dict(**d1, d2)` do the same thing as `dict(d1, **d2)`?
3. Somewhat related to Q1 - from my understanding of what `**kwargs` does, it somehow expands the dictionary out into its `key = value` and when applied to me example, probably gave me something like `In [200]: dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, e='f', g='h', i='j')` as it ran correctly. But doesn't this look like there were 4 arguments? Why didn't this throw an error?
4. My last question is why when using the `key = value` pair syntax as arguments into `dict`, we do not need to enclose the `key` in any quotes, but only do it for the `value`, despite the key itself being a `string` object too as is evident in the outputs from the successful `dict` constructions?

Thank you all very much for your help, and I will appreciate any comments or suggestions here too that may not be directly related to my problems here. This behavior just seems so obscure to me, and I can't understand it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior isn't obscure at all if you read the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)

Remember that when you call `dict()`, you are calling a function. Functions have a defined number of parameters, and these parameters have a defined order.

There are three definitions of `dict()`, namely:

```
dict(**kwargs)
dict(iterable, **kwargs)
dict(mapping, **kwargs)
```

It's simply just how the language was designed. This should answer your questions in (1) and (2).

EDIT: For (3), you're right in thinking that it expands the key/value pairs out. `**kwargs` is `n` number of named parameters, so when you pass `i=1, j=2, k=3` you are passing 3 named parameters. If a function is defined with `**kwargs` as a param, that means it can receive `0 to n` named parameters. There's a distinction between a normal param and a named param.

For (4), this is just a compiler trick. It's there for convenience I guess, but in practice it is rarely used. I personally have yet to see the `key=value` convention used in the "real world". YMMV.

Comment: good answer! I was wondering about this as well after reading the question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I guess this answers my concerns. But for question 3, if what really happeend, as you say, is that the expansion only occurs in the function, then why did it work for me when I did `In [200]: dict({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, e='f', g='h', i='j')` which is an argument that I pass to the function (and thus happens outside)?

Comment: Oh right, thank you. So what you mean to say is that `**kwargs` in itself, although is one argument and this satisfies the condition that `dict(**kwargs)` only accepts one argument, `**kwargs` itself can hold up to `n` parameters? So what determines the value of `n`? Or can `**kwargs` hold any arbitrary number of named parameters? I've noticed that in Python, anything to do with `*` or `**`generally means something to do with "unlimited" or "everything", similar to the wildcard in shell scripting. Are they related?

Comment: `n` is another way of saying `zero to many`. So `dict(**kwargs)` means that `dict()` can take anywhere from zero to an "unlimited" number of named parameters. You can either pass them as `**kwargs` or as `a=1, b=2, c=3`.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies pretty much everything I have for this question.